# PHP, error Undefined offset

Tags: php, undefined, offset

I have a script that lists a few Twitch.tv streams and shows if they are offline or online. 
I'm trying to integrate it in one of my pages, but I'm getting several Undefined offset errors.

This is the script:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Streamlist</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

$members = array("painuser","ZombieGrub","Nathanias","Youbetterknowme","ncl_tv");

// This variable becomes one long url with the channel names stringed up behind it
// This url then fetches a json file from twitch with all the selected channels information
$userGrab = "http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=";
$userGrab .= implode(",", $members);


//I use this array to compare with the members array. All users in this arrat are substracted from the members array and hence are //"offline"
$checkedOnline = array (); 

foreach($members as $i =>$value){
$userGrab .= ",";
$userGrab .= $value;

}
unset($value);

//grabs the channel data from twitch.tv streams
$json_file = file_get_contents($userGrab, 0, null, null);
$json_array = json_decode($json_file, true);

//get's member names from stream url's and checks for online members
$channels = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($members); $i++) {
 $title = $json_array[$i]['channel']['channel_url'];
$array = explode('/', $title);
$member = end($array);
$viewer = $json_array[$i] ['stream_count'];
onlinecheck($member, $viewer);
$checkedOnline[] = signin($member);
}

unset($value);
unset($i);

//checks if player streams are online
function onlinecheck($online, $viewers)
{  
//If the variable online is not equal to null, there is a good change this person is currently streaming
if ($online != null)
{
echo '<a href="http://www.twitch.tv/'.$online.'"> <strong>'.$online.'</strong></a>';
echo '&nbsp <img src="/images/online.png"><strong> Status:</strong> Online! </br>'; 
echo '<img src="/images/viewers.png"><strong>Viewers:</strong> &nbsp' .$viewers.'</br>';

}
}

//This funcion add's online channel names to the checked online array
function signin($person){
if($person != null){
return $person;
}
else{
return null;
}
}

?>
<hr>
<?php
//This part list all the people currently offline. Here the array with online users is compared with the total users.
//online users are then removed from the total users array.
foreach ($members as $i => $value1) {
foreach($checkedOnline as $ii => $value2){
if($value1 == $value2){
unset($members[$i]);
}
}

}
//print a nice list with people that can't currently be bothered with streaming their games 
foreach ($members as $ii => $value2) {
echo '<a href="http://www.twitch.tv/'.$online.'"> <strong>'.$online.'</strong></a>';
echo '&nbsp <img src="/images/online.png"><strong> Status:</strong> Online! </br>'; 
echo '<img src="/images/viewers.png"><strong>Viewers:</strong> &nbsp' .$viewers.'</br>';
echo '<a href="http://www.twitch.tv/'.$value.'"> <strong>'.$value.'</strong></a>';
echo '&nbsp<img src="/images/offline.png"> <strong> Status :</strong> Offline! </br>';

}


?>
</body>
</html>
```

After this, I'm using this code to display the streams:

```
//This part list all the people currently offline. Here the array with online users is compared with the total users.
//online users are then removed from the total users array.
foreach ($members as $i => $value1) {
foreach($checkedOnline as $ii => $value2){
if($value1 == $value2){
unset($members[$i]);
}
}

}
//print a nice list with people that can't currently be bothered with streaming their games 
foreach ($members as $i => $value) {
echo '<a href="http://www.twitch.tv/'.$value.'"> <strong>'.$value.'</strong></a>';
echo '&nbsp<img src="/images/offline.png"> <strong> Status :</strong> Offline! </br>';
}
```

Now, the errors.
I'm getting this:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\twitchlist\twitchlist.php on line 42

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\twitchlist\twitchlist.php on line 45

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\twitchlist\twitchlist.php on line 42

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\twitchlist\twitchlist.php on line 45

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\twitchlist\twitchlist.php on line 42

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\twitchlist\twitchlist.php on line 45

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\twitchlist\twitchlist.php on line 42

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\themes\fesport\sidebar.php on line 75

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\themes\fesport\sidebar.php on line 84
```

Can someone help? Is there a way to solve this?
I'm not that good at PHP and I don't know what to do.

Edit:
Second errors...

```
zombiegrub   Status: Online! 
Viewers:  588
nathanias   Status: Online! 
Viewers:  178
youbetterknowme   Status: Online! 
Viewers:  80
painuser   Status: Online! 
Viewers:  47

Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\twitchlist\twitchlist.php on line 34

Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\twitchlist\twitchlist.php on line 37

Notice: Undefined variable: online in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\twitchlist\twitchlist.php on line 83

Notice: Undefined variable: online in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\twitchlist\twitchlist.php on line 83
Status: Online! 

Notice: Undefined variable: viewers in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\twitchlist\twitchlist.php on line 85
Viewers:  

Notice: Undefined variable: value in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\twitchlist\twitchlist.php on line 86

Notice: Undefined variable: value in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\twitchlist\twitchlist.php on line 86
Status : Offline! 

Notice: Undefined variable: online in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\twitchlist\twitchlist.php on line 83

Notice: Undefined variable: online in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\twitchlist\twitchlist.php on line 83
Status: Online! 

Notice: Undefined variable: viewers in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\twitchlist\twitchlist.php on line 85
Viewers:  

Notice: Undefined variable: value in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\twitchlist\twitchlist.php on line 86

Notice: Undefined variable: value in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\twitchlist\twitchlist.php on line 86
Status : Offline! 

Notice: Undefined variable: online in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\twitchlist\twitchlist.php on line 83

Notice: Undefined variable: online in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\twitchlist\twitchlist.php on line 83
Status: Online! 

Notice: Undefined variable: viewers in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\twitchlist\twitchlist.php on line 85
Viewers:  

Notice: Undefined variable: value in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\twitchlist\twitchlist.php on line 86

Notice: Undefined variable: value in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\twitchlist\twitchlist.php on line 86
Status : Offline! 

Notice: Undefined variable: online in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\twitchlist\twitchlist.php on line 83

Notice: Undefined variable: online in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\twitchlist\twitchlist.php on line 83
Status: Online! 

Notice: Undefined variable: viewers in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\twitchlist\twitchlist.php on line 85
Viewers:  

Notice: Undefined variable: value in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\twitchlist\twitchlist.php on line 86

Notice: Undefined variable: value in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\twitchlist\twitchlist.php on line 86
Status : Offline! 

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\themes\sahifa\sidebar.php on line 75

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\themes\sahifa\sidebar.php on line 84
```

Comment: Can you open the file as shown in the error and let us know exactly which line is line 42 and line 45. That will make it easier to help you.

Comment: Line 42: $title = $json_array['$i']['channel']['channel_url'];

Comment: Line 45: $viewer = $json_array['$i'] ['stream_count'];

Comment: Try to print_r or var_dump the contents of $json_array. User this to see the content of that variable. **echo '<pre>',print_r($json_array),'</pre>';** Just do as the code I've written under the line where you decode the json_string and see what it has. It could be empty thus your looking for undefined keys in the array.

Comment: Are you sure the other server is even sending you a JSON string? The is the purpose of the above line I want you to add. Just to make sure because you might not be getting anything. It's really hard to help without knowing the format of the data sent to you by the other server at twitch.tv.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
 $json_array['$i']....
```

PHP treats strings inside of single quotes as string literals - in this case, you're looking for an array value of `$i`, rather than the value. If you want to interpolate values inside a string, you should use double quotes:

```
 $json_array["$i"]....
```

But since you're just using the value of the variable, you don't need quotes at all:

```
 $json_array[$i]....
```

Edit:

You can try this, too. If you're supposed to be passing an array of comma-separated values, your code will give you an extra comma at the start:

```
$members = array("maegis","androide456","avonmexicola","iksf");

$usergrab .= implode(",", $members);
```

Edit the second:

The JSON that's being returned is an array; so to iterate through it, you need a simple loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($members); $i++) {
     $title = $json_array[$i]['channel']['channel_url'];
     ....
```

Comment: Okay, edited. However I'm still getting Undefined offset, no matter if I use double quotes or not.

Comment: In that case, you're going to have to do as Touch suggested, and `var_dump($json_array)` so you can see the format. Could you edit that into your question?

Comment: Edited now in my question too. var_dump($json_array) returned format NULL.

Comment: I've added another suggestion. You need to make sure that your file_get_contents call is returning data properly.

Comment: It's actually not working properly. I've set now this $members = array("painuser","ZombieGrub","Nathanias","Youbetterknowme","ncl_tv"); Yet it's still returning array("maegis","androide456","avonmexicola","iksf")

Comment: Btw, I used this ` foreach($members as $i =>$value){
    $channels[] = $value;
 $title = $json_array[$i]['channel']['channel_url'];
 $array = explode('/', $title);
 $member = end($array);
 $viewer = $json_array[$i] ['stream_count'];
 onlinecheck($member, $viewer);
 $checkedOnline[] = signin($member);
 }
 
 $userGrab .= implode(",", $channels)` and it doesn't work

Comment: There's a much easier way of doing the `implode` - I've edited again. Your `$members` is a plain array, and the `foreach ($members as $i => $value)` isn't going to work - to iterate through, you can just do `foreach ($members as $i)`.

Comment: Ok, did that. But the stupid script is still returning the old $members, even when I change them. Absolutely no change..

Comment: Can you echo out the `$usergrab` string that you're passing to `file_get_contents()`?

Comment: It doesn't return anything :(

Comment: Tarnation - it's `$userGrab`, not `$usergrab`. PHP is case sensitive for variable names.

Comment: Yeah I know, I'm using $userGrab

Comment: Well I was doing this wrong. Check the first post, I pasted the full code and you can see all errors on http://212.233.229.27/wp-content/plugins/twitchlist/twitchlist.php

Comment: Echo-ing $userGrab returns http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=painuser,ZombieGrub,Nathanias,Youbetterknowme,ncl_tv,painuser,ZombieGrub,Nathanias,Youbetterknowme,ncl_tv

Comment: @MarinaTodorova - if you click on that link, it shows you the JSON that's being returned. One second, and I'll amend my code.

Comment: @MarinaTodorova - how's that?

Comment: That worked great! It's finally returning the correct streams and their status! But I'm still getting a few errors.. check my first post for "Second errors"

Comment: You might be better off adding this as a separate question, as I need to sign off imminently; but I'd suggest replacing `$member = end($array);` with `$member = $members[$i]`;

Comment: Well, that removed almost all of the errors except Undefined offset on 34 and 37, but now it shows all streams as online, even when they are not. :(